# How are some deb packages found by dpkg-query while they have never been installed?

Tags: debian, dpkg

Why are some packages found by `dpkg-query` as with `unknown` desired action and with `not-installed` status while other packages are not found at all? For example I have never installed package named `debian-handbook`, but it somehow shows up in output of `dpkg-query -l debian-handbook` or `dpkg-query -s debian-handbook`. On the other hand, for example some packages, which I have also never touched, do not show up in output of `dpkg -l`:

```
root@T60:~# dpkg -l gkermit
dpkg-query: no packages found matching gkermit
root@T60:~# apt-cache policy gkermit
gkermit:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.0-9
  Version table:
     1.0-9 0
        500 http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie/main i386 Packages
root@T60:~#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `dpkg -l` finds packages that are mentioned as dependencies of packages that are currently installed, and doesn't find other available packages. (Here “installed” includes “conffiles-only” packages, i.e. packages that have been removed but not purged, listed as `uc` in `dpkg -l`.) `dpkg -l` lists packages that are mentioned in the dpkg `status` file (`/var/lib/dpkg/status`).

There may be other reasons that determine whether a package is listed by `dpkg -l`, but I think this is the main one.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like packages which are `Recommends` or `Suggests` also show up in output of `dpkg -l`.

Comment: Here are results of my [investigation](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/3c311799c1b3e722501b78575473061f).